# GraphQL query with filters doesn't include all expected results

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I'm working in the AWS AppSync Queries web client to construct queries to use in a GraphQL Amplify React app and I am getting some unexpected results.

Please consider the following queries...

```
query MyQuery {
  listDirectoryListings(filter: {location_search_name: {contains: "safe"}}) {
    items { location_name }
  }
}
```

The query above returns 3 records. However, the actual data has 263 records that contain "safe". I confirmed this locally with an export from DynamoDB.

Comment: Try using the 'limit' filter , set limit filter to 300.

Comment: The project that used AppSync was abandoned, so I cannot test this.

Comment: @Baazigar007 It did work for me, but what the logic of setting the limit to 300?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding limt to the query ?

```
query MyQuery {
  listDirectoryListings(filter: {location_search_name: {contains: "safe"}}, limit: 1000) {
    items { location_name }
  }
}
```

Hope it is can hepl you

Comment: The project that used AppSync was abandoned for other reasons, so unfortunately, I cannot test this. Though, this seems like the right answer.